# Ionic exporting SVG to image, works on Android, image cutted on IOS

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, svg

I have an svg that gets exported as a base64 encoded image and send to the server where further stored on Google Cloud Storage. This procedure works perfectly on Android and in Browser but fails when tried on physical device running IOS. What happens on IOS is the image is cut, only 25% of the image is visible, like it is over-stretched. Bellow is the current code

```
    let mySVG = document.getElementById('svg'),      // Inline SVG element
        can = document.createElement('canvas'), // Not shown on page
        ctx = can.getContext('2d'),
        loader = new Image;                        // Not shown on page
    loader.width = can.width = mySVG.clientWidth;
    loader.height = can.height = mySVG.clientHeight;
    let executed = false;
    loader.onload = () => {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            ctx.drawImage(loader, 0, 0, loader.width, loader.height);
            let svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(mySVG);
            loader.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML);
            let svgElement = document.getElementById('svg');
            let svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);
            let decoded = unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgString));
            let base64 = btoa(decoded);
            let imgSource = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${base64}`;
            let s = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById('svg'));
            let encodedData = window.btoa(s);
            this.storage.get('appointment').then(appointment => {
                if (appointment && appointment.id) {
                    this.APIService.POST('api/drawing', {
                        appointment: appointment.id,
                        annotations: this.annotations,
                        drawing: can.toDataURL()
                    }, (err, message, data) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return this.toastService.showToast('primary', message);
                        } else {
                            return this.toastService.showToast('primary', 'Drawing uploaded.');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
    var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(mySVG);
    loader.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML);
```

Answer (score 0):

After lots of time spent writing the code for this, the problem is solved using the following library from npm [save-svg-as-png](https://www.npmjs.com/package/save-svg-as-png) package.